# Is it possible to have a maven configuration look at a a local nexus storage location first?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, nexus, bamboo

We have Jenkins (and Bamboo) on the same server as our nexus server. I would like to know if it's possible to have the maven `~/.m2/settings.xml` configuration first check within the nexus disk location first before downloading artefacts?

Sonatype seems to store in the same structure as Maven does though with a parent directory of the repository id. i.e.

`/data/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar`

I don't want Jenkins to be able to actually download to this location as this I perceive could be dangerous, however I'd like to have it first consult this location. Jenkins can then freely download what it pleases if it does not exist which will then trigger Nexus to also download the artefact first; this double up can then be solved by creating a black-out for Jenkins at night time to prevent builds from occurring while a batch script checks for duplicated files and removes them from the Jenkins local repository.

Comment: I setup a 'routed' repository that all my projects use.  releases -> snapshots -> 3rdparty -> routed -> central.  The goal of my 'routed' is to proxy all other external repos so that providing the proxy is hot I can network disconnect central and still build.  I reserve '3rdparty' for projects we have obtained direct from 3rd party (with SLA/agreement or that we have downloaded, audited and manually built the open-source project) i.e. they pass whatever the internal auditing policy is.  Also don't actually use external repos direct from your project always use nexus proxy to central/wherever.

Comment: Thanks Darryl, we do exactly the same, though there will still end up being a duplicate cache when it hits the build server which is the same server as the nexus server. Our nexus config is fine, I just want Jenkins to use that same file system first.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I am going to guess that you are trying to save disk space and have Maven not download files that are already downloaded by nexus. This will not work. The best you can do is have a repository with a `file:` url first in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` which will mean that the nexus on disk gets checked first and then the file will be copied from there to `~/.m2/repository` however that will  give corrupt downloads and not save disk, only save network traffic on `127.0.0.1` interface

Comment: Exactly, the Jenkins maven cache is presently 4Gb which is all duplicated in the nexus storage on the same host as everything proxies through nexus.

Comment: Well then you are SooL. The best you can do is purge the local cache and let Maven redownload it all from Nexus again. That will at least remove old -SNAPSHOTs and clear out no-longer-used dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Use mvn with offline option （mvn --help ->

```
-o,--offline                           Work offline

$ mvn -offline
```